# Need to create a new dataset using specific values read from a database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataset

I am working on a project and I need to create a new dataset using data read from a sql server database. I need to display the name and contact information of clients that haven't ordered any products in the last four weeks. The clients table in the database contains a column specifically recording the last order date of a client. How can i compare that date to today's date and add the relevant info to a new dataset that can be used to display in a datagridview.

Thanks in advance.

```
string inactiveClient = "SELECT CustomerName, CustomerNumber FROM Customers";

        int dateNow = DateTime.Now.Month;
        int yearNow = DateTime.Now.Year;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(inactiveClient, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string orderDate = sdr["LastOrderDate"].ToString();

                    int orderYear = Convert.ToInt32(orderDate.Remove(5));
                    orderDate = orderDate.Remove(0, 5);
                    orderDate = orderDate.Remove(3, 4);
                    int orderMonth = Convert.ToInt32(orderDate);

                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        if ((orderYear <= yearNow) && (orderMonth < dateNow))
                        {
                            // Add to new dataset
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This was my basic idea.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: so whats your exact problem, SQL Query? or something else

Comment: In you sql query use a where with a parameter which is the date you want to compare against : WHERE 'Last order date' <  @parameter

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt My problem is that i don't have any idea how I can test for the diffenerence in the dates, except by breaking the date up into parts, and the other problem is I don't know how to create a new dataset or adding new rows from a database.

Comment: @jdweng I have thought of trying exactly that, but it needs to be more than four weeks, that will return dates that are just days before today's date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Bas I have deleted all my code regarding that because none of it worked and none of it was a viable solution to my problem

Comment: Simple if you thought a little bit more : DateTime parameter = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30);

Comment: @jdweng I'm still new to sql / c# coding and did't know about that method. But thank you, that looks like exactly what i needed. But thank you, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to get all records and do the filtering yourself on the client. Use the fact that you have a database server.

```
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerNumber FROM Customers 
    WHERE LastOrderDate < DATEADD(week, -4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I'm assuming you are using MS SQL Server and your LastOrderDate is a DATETIME column. If you are storing dates in text, you should change that.